# How to draw shape for each image color and how to set number for each of the color?

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv

The image has 11 different colors.

> An example showing what I need to get is given in the picture:

[image: Example]

I need to map each color to number and to see shape.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you got the Color in an Array of x,y try

```
xdiff,ydiff=np.Gradient(Colormap)
shape=np.Logical_and(xdiff,ydiff)
```

it should give you an Image of the spots were the Color changes.

```
np.unique(Colormap)
```

gives you all the Colors present

Comment: Thanks for answer. 
I get unique colors, but i am not sure how to get Colormap?
Only what i have is image in array.

Comment: What do you mean by colormap? What is the desired result. You should have the outlines in shape and all Colors present. Do you want to print the numbers in the middle of the Patches?

Comment: I am not sure what is colormap, in answer i see np.Gradient(Colormap) colormap, but i not shure what is it. Yes i want to print the numbers in the middle of the Patches. Thank you for trying to help with me.

Comment: colormap is a 2d Array with the Colors in it. (probably your imagearray)